# 502 Bad Gateway Docker + Laravel

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx

I've started to learn Docker. I have Laravel application and want to start it in docker containers. But I can't run it correctly.

I have this `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

And this `vhost.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

app.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.3-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    cron \
    mysql-client \
    vim \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

web.dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

After run containers I have `502 Bad Gateway` and in web container I have this:
 `connect() failed (111: Connections refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: request "GET /HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.19.0.3:9000", host: "192.168.99.101:8080"`.

I very bad at server settings and don't understand what happened. Will be very grateful for every help.

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly is the issue, but your web containers cannot connect to the app containers. Can you try to ping your app container from the web container. `ping app`. If the containers are not able to ping each other try to include a network that the containers share.

Comment: I can ping from `web` to `app`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by php listening on localhost and does not accept external connections. You should update you `php.ini` to listen on 0.0.0.0.

you could test this by running the following command on your app container. And try to telnet from the web container to the app container.

```
/usr/bin/php -S 0.0.0.0:9000

telnet app 9000
```

If, for some reason that command fails try to edit your php-fpm config to set the listen address to `0.0.0.0:9000`

Example:

```
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv4 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   '[ip:6:addr:ess]:port' - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific IPv6 address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.

listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
```